# custom xml parse function for google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I'm trying to replace the importXML function of googledocs because of its limit to use it only 50 items.

The current formula would be:

```
=ImportXML($K$10,"sum(//row[@typeid='"B1&"']/@quantity)")
```

Where the K10 cell contains an url to fetch the XML that looks like this:

```
<eveapi version="2">
  <currentTime>2012-09-09 09:33:55</currentTime>
  <result>
    <rowset name="assets" key="itemID" columns="itemID,locationID,typeID,quantity,flag,singleton">
      <row itemID="1003898262197" locationID="31001059" typeID="17167" quantity="1" flag="0" singleton="1" rawQuantity="-1">
        <rowset name="contents" key="itemID" columns="itemID,typeID,quantity,flag,singleton">
      <row itemID="1003962719504" typeID="253" quantity="3" flag="0" singleton="0"/>
        </rowset>
      </row>
      <row itemID="1003898281453" locationID="31001059" typeID="17408" quantity="1" flag="0" singleton="1" rawQuantity="-1">
        <rowset name="contents" key="itemID" columns="itemID,typeID,quantity,flag,singleton">
      <row itemID="1003962379527" typeID="253" quantity="3" flag="0" singleton="0"/>
        </rowset>
      </row>
      <row itemID="1003908898633" locationID="31001059" typeID="17175" quantity="1" flag="0" singleton="1" rawQuantity="-1"/>
      <row itemID="1003908901859" locationID="31001059" typeID="17174" quantity="1" flag="0" singleton="1" rawQuantity="-1"/>
      <row itemID="1003908954610" locationID="31001059" typeID="17177" quantity="1" flag="0" singleton="1" rawQuantity="-1"/>
    </rowset>
  </result>
  <cachedUntil>2012-09-09 10:20:25</cachedUntil>
</eveapi>
```

What i'm trying to do (as you perhaps can see from the ImportXML formula) is to get a sum of the quantity values of a particular typeID. The typeID would be an imput parameter of the function.

```
function _retrieveXML() {
  // https://api.eveonline.com/corp/AssetList.xml.aspx?keyID=688782&vCode=q52TpGFTqNCziMMmZ7TYgpXCoGa7U0VBxyH7LuS6Ubtdakbi5t5UDMyf1U5WLpZA&characterID=90127511
  var keyID = "xxxxxx"
  var vCode = "q52TpGFTqNCziMMmZ7TYgpXCoGa7U0VBxyH7LuS6Ubtdakbi5t5UDMyf1U5WLpZA"
  var characterID = "xxxxxxxx"
  var parameters = {
    method : "post",
    payload : "keyID=" + keyID + "&vCode=" + vCode + "&characterID=" + characterID
  };  
  var xmlFeed = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.eveonline.com/corp/AssetList.xml.aspx",parameters);    
  var xmldoc = Xml.parse(xmlFeed.getContentText(), false);
  var records = xmldoc.eveapi.result.rowset.getElements("typeID");  
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = doc.getRange('a1');
  var index = 0;  
  for (var i in xmldoc) {
    var row = xmldoc[i];
    cell.offset(index, 0).setValue(row[i]);
    }
    index++;
  }
```

I'm lost on how to get the information into a usable format for a google spreadsheet. How to retrieve a certain value of one of the objects (like typeID, quantity) and use them to retrieve another value in that same line.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The key issue here is that Custom Functions have very  (scroll all the way to the bottom). You wont be able to call any standard spreadsheet functions from there. You can only return strings and arrays.

The better way to do it might be trigger from a user action. Have a drawing or a menu in the spreadsheet that triggers the same script.